# How do I get rid of a re-appearing B&W hard drive icon on my macOS desktop?

Tags: macos, external-disk, icon, desktop

I have an iMac running OS X Yosemite 10.10.5 and an external hard drive with 3 partitions.

The external HD was unplugged and left unplugged. Since then, it appears on my desktop at every startup, black and white. It can be ejected anytime (with <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> or Disk Utility) but keeps coming back every startup.

If I plug in the HD, it also appears in color in addition to the false B&W HD icons. It can be ejected and doesn't come back unless I plug it in again. Clicking on the false icon shows the correct menu, and all docs and apps can also be accessed.

How do I get rid of the B&W icons?

Comment: Have you tried booting into Safe Mode? Safe Mode clears caches and does some other behind-the-scenes maintenance. Do that by starting (or choosing restart) while pressing the Shift key. More here: support.apple.com/en-us/HT201262